# Is there a way to add multiple Ints together?

Tags: java

How do I add Ints or Floats together in Java(or BlueJ)? I mean not that:

```
x=2;
y=3;
System.out.println(y+x);
```

and then comes 5 out, I mean rather like this:

```
x=2;
y=3;
c=y+x;
System.out.println(c);
```

And here should come out 32. Not  adding like in Math, rather like combining these things in one new variable.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: use this - c=""+y+x

Comment: There are at least two and probably more ways to interpret this question. What, *specifically*, do you expect in `c`? A string? An `int` with the value thirty-two? An `int` in a superposition of the values 3 and 2? (Not going to happen on consumer hardware and an even vaguely standard JVM.) An `int` array with 3 and 2 in it?

Comment: What you want is not addition of mathematical `int` values but rather interpreting the values as `String`s and then using *string concatenation*. So the steps are: transform your values to `String`s and then use *string concatenation*. After that transform back to an `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

Concat your number with a `String`:

```
String c = "" + x + y;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I don't get the downvotes.

Comment: Its not clear from the question but I think OP also wants to get the result back as `int` again. So you may add `Integer.parseInt(...)`.